# É possível programar usando a API WinRT sem recorrer ao XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, xaml, programação-imperativa

Há algum tempo linguagens declarativas tomaram conta do desenvolvimento de softwares para criação de interfaces gráficas com o usuário. Os exemplos mais óbvios são o *framework* [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que usa a XAML (eXtensible Application Markup Language) como linguagem declarativa e a biblioteca [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) framework com sua QML (Qt Markup Language).

Ao contrário da Qt que não expõe publicamente o código (classes) responsável pela efetiva execução da interface, obrigando o uso do QML no novo estilo de GUI (QtWidgets é o oposto) e não permite um modo de programação imperativa ao invés de declarativa (pelo menos não permite fazer 100% em código), o WPF permite dois modos de programação: 1) declarativamente através do XAML, que é o modo mais utilizado e 2) programação imperativa/orientada a objeto com código através das classes expostas, afinal a XAML é toda construída em cima das classes existentes, contando até com classes auxiliares para converter valores de XAML para código. Grosso modo, há uma relação 1:1 entre classes e seus membros e as marcações do código XAML e seus atributos.

Apesar de ostensivamente demonstrado que a XAML deve ser utilizada prioritariamente - isto ter várias vantagens - e até mesmo algumas pessoas acreditarem que é a única forma, a documentação, livros sobre o WPF, e alguns [sites até específicos sobre o assunto](http://wpftutorial.net/XAML.html)<sup>(en)</sup> (também [aqui](http://www.tbiro.com/Hello-WPF-Without-XAML.htm)<sup>(en)</sup> e no [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729087/wpf-without-xaml)<sup>(en)</sup>) indicam claramente a possibilidade de usar apenas a programação não declarativa.

Eu tenho um software que gera todas as telas *on-the-fly*, através de código. Adaptando este software para o Windows 8, seria até um absurdo em tempo de execução eu gerar o XAML para depois o *framework* "converter em código" para ser executado.

Não conheço bem a tecnologia e não sei se valeria aprender para muito mais tarde descobrir se não atenderá minha necessidade.

Já procurei exaustivamente na internet de forma geral e em sites específicos se isso também é possível e nada encontrei. Não consegui achar nada que indicasse que é possível ou mesmo que não é. Não fui capaz de achar um exemplo sequer mostrando apenas código. Certamente achei muito código que auxilia o XAML da WinRT mas nada que indique que 100% da interface pode ser feita sem XAML.

Minha dúvida é se há possibilidade de usar a WinRT para construção de GUI sem usar nada de XAML, só com código, e é claro, onde posso achar informações/documentação a respeito, se possível com exemplos. Em outras palavras, 100% do código responsável pela construção e interação da GUI está exposta ao programador? Algum exemplo aqui seria muito bem-vindo.

Não está em debate a utilidade da XAML. Para esse **caso específico** seria um exagero.

Pra mim vale o mesmo para a WinUI.

Comment: Para WinRT é possível usar HTML em vez de XAML. Se você só criar objetos via javascript, acredito que isso responde a sua pergunta (sem XAML e só via código). Mas acredito que essa não é a resposta que você está procurando, se for, irei transferir para a seção de respostas.

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Você até tem razão que não é bem isso que procuro, mas não deixa de ser uma resposta que pode ajudar quem pode usar dessa forma e isso é importante também. Não aceitaria como **A** resposta, mas é uma possível. Você tem conhecimento se essa é a única forma, ou não arriscaria dizer isso?

Comment: Segue a url de um video, que apesar de antigo, trata sobre o que seria o passado, presente e futuro do XAML: 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Rob-Relyea-Theres-Something-About-XAML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WPF não tem nada a ver com HTML!

É possível utilizar WPF sem XAML (XAML na verdade sempre é traduzido para C#).

É tão simples quanto Windows Forms:

Ex.: Vamos supor que eu queira fazer uma página (não confundir com página web) para um app Windows 8 com um `label` e um botão, com *binding*:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace App1
{
public class TestPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
{

    public TestPage()
    {
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        var label = new TextBlock { Text = "Hello World" };
        var button = new Button();
        var buttonCaption = new TextBlock();

        buttonCaption.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding { Path = new Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath("Text"), Source = label });
        button.Content = buttonCaption;

        stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(button);

        var layoutRoot = new Grid
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center,
        };

        layoutRoot.Children.Add(stackPanel);
        Content = layoutRoot;
        }

        }
```

}

Respondendo as dúvidas do comentário:

Isso é WinRT (ou seja, Silverlight para Windows Store Apps).

Não tenho referências além da documentação do XAML. Tudo o que o XAML faz, existe uma classe correspondente. Se você tem `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `Button`, etc. no XAML, fatalmente as terá no namespace do WPF (seja ele qual versão for). Isso inclui até recursos como *binding* e *static resources*.

Não há "lugar com autoridade que afirme...", mas isso é intrínseco. C# não compila nem roda XAML, ele no máximo interpreta e monta a tela com os objetos contidos no `namespace Windows.UI.Xaml`. Não há nada que exista em XAML que não exista neste *namespace* (afinal, no final das contas, não existe XAML).

Você pode realizar qualquer tarefa desta forma, embora isso seja bem ruim. XAML facilita a escrita e realiza alguns atalhos que, para fazer manualmente, você deverá recorrer à documentação. Um exemplo disto é colocar um texto dentro de um botão. No XAML, é simples. Em código você deve explicitamente especificar que o conteúdo do botão é um `TextBlock` (algo como um `Label`).

Você está confundindo um pouco as coisas. XAML é apenas o nome do *markup* (ele nunca é executado de fato, sempre é convertido ou interpretado). O fato de o *namespace* se chamar XAML é porque a MS intencionou o WPF para ser utilizado com um auxílio da linguagem de *markup* e não existe absolutamente nenhum motivo para não se utilizar isso, pelo menos em parte. O *binding* do WPF é suficientemente poderoso para evitar criar componentes na mão. Mas, claro, .net é um *framework* que te dá liberdade pra fazer o que quiser.

Comment: Muito interessante. Acho que está chegando onde quero. Vamos à algumas dúvidas: você disse "É possível utilizar WPF sem XAML". Você entendeu que eu sei disso e que a minha dúvida é sobre fazer o mesmo com a WinRT? Esse seu exemplo foi tirado de onde? Tem alguma referência onde posso achar mais exemplos? Tem algum lugar com autoridade que afirme que dá para usar WinRT 100% com código e zero XAML? Coisas mais complexas podem ser feitas desta forma também? Tem alguma ideia porque isso tudo está em namespace Xaml quando ele não está sendo usado? Se puder editar para colocar essas dúvidas...

Comment: Tem algum link para documentação que mostre alguns exemplos como o que você postou para eu poder fazer alguns estudos? Tenho visto só XAML. Por isso fiquei achando que só o XAML era possível. Parece que escondem que pode usar código. Ao contrário do WPF que a documentação frequentemente mostra as duas formas.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o [Marcos Zolnowski](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64/marcos-zolnowski):

Para WinRT é possível usar HTML em vez de XAML. Se você só criar objetos via javascript, acredito que isso responde a sua pergunta (sem XAML e só via código). Mas acredito que essa não é a resposta que você está procurando, se for, irei transferir para a seção de respostas.

---

Eu acrescentaria que é possível fazer a criação dinâmica de elementos [assim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189044(v=vs.95).aspx):

```cs
        // Popula contatos do XElement com informações de Contacts.  
        XElement contacts =
            new XElement("Contacts",
                new XElement("Contact1",
                    new XElement("Name", "Patrick Hines"),
                    new XElement("Phone", "206-555-0144"),
                    new XElement("Address",
                        new XElement("Street1", "123 Main St"),
                        new XElement("City", "Mercer Island"),
                        new XElement("State", "WA"),
                        new XElement("Postal", "68042")
                    )
                ),
                new XElement("Contact2",
                    new XElement("Name", "Yoshi Latime"),
                    new XElement("Phone", "503-555-6874"),
                    new XElement("Address",
                        new XElement("Street1", "City Center Plaza 516 Main St."),
                        new XElement("City", "Elgin"),
                        new XElement("State", "OR"),
                        new XElement("Postal", "97827")
                    )
                )
            );

        // Cria o primeiro controle TextBlock.
        // Note que o elemento precisa declarar dois namespaces XAML.
        XElement textBlock1 = XElement.Parse(
                @"<TextBlock 
    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007' 
    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' 
    TextWrapping= 'Wrap'
    Width = '400'
    Canvas.Top = '10'
    Text=''/>");

        // Pega o primeiro elemento filho da árvore de contatos do xml.
        XElement contact1 = contacts.Element("Contact1");

        // Ajusta o valor do último atributo "Text"
        // com o conteúdo dos contatos da árvore do xml.
        textBlock1.LastAttribute.SetValue(contact1.ToString());


        // Pega o segundo elemento filho da árvore de contatos do xml.
        XElement contact2 = contacts.Element("Contact2");

        // Cria o segundo controle TextBlock.
        // Note que o elemento precisa declarar dois namespaces XAML.
        XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007";
        XElement textBlock2 = new XElement(xmlns + "TextBlock",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"),
            new XAttribute("Canvas.Top", 250),
            new XAttribute("Width", "600"),
            new XAttribute("Text", contact2.ToString())
            );


        // Adiciona o controle TextBlock à página
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(XamlReader.Load(textBlock1.ToString()) as UIElement);
        // Adiciona o controle TextBlock à página
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(XamlReader.Load(textBlock2.ToString()) as UIElement);
```

Comment: Agradeço o exemplo, mas realmente ainda não é o que eu estou procurando. Eu gostaria de evitar criar tudo isso. Talvez não tenha jeito. Depois preciso perguntar sobre como é feito no iOS e Android usando Xamarin.

Comment: @bigown Explique um pouco melhor o que você precisa então, por favor. Eu tinha entendido que você queria poder criar os componentes todos dinamicamente sem o XAML. Isso é bem verboso mesmo quando é feito tudo programaticamente.

Comment: Quando ao Xamarin.iOS e o Xamarin.Android abra uma pergunta lá que eu respondo. Esses eu uso sempre e com alguma frequencia preciso criar na mão os componentes.

Comment: Essa perguntas eu vou fazer depois com calma. O que eu queria é programar como no WPF, onde você acessa diretamente as classes que vão executar o código. O XAML é uma camada sobre essas classes. No caso que você mostrou o XAML está sendo usado. Indiretamente, mas é ele que está comandando a execução. Eu não sei se é possível. Mas nunca encontrei alguém dizendo claramente que não é. A sua solução pode até ser usada se não houver outra forma, mas ela é mais ou menos o que eu sabia que dava pra fazer. Pode ser um pouco difícil entender porque quase ninguém usa o WPF programaticamente.

Comment: Eu acho que isso é o mais programaticamente que tem como fazer. Até onde eu sei o WPF foi construído para ter uma camada de abstração da View que é o HTML ou XAML. Creio não ser possível fazer com ele. Mas se vai fazer tudo programaticamente por que usar o WPF, por que não usar o WinForms ou outro Framework?

Comment: Posso afirmar por experiência que dá para fazer 100% programaticamente em WPF e é quase igual fazer para WinForms que é uma tecnologia que não atendia bem as necessidades. Agora há a necessidade de criar uma camada de apresentação para outros dispositivos onde nem o WinForms, nem o WPF funcionam. E de qualquer forma seria melhor usar sempre algo nativo. Há muita desinformação sobre o WPF. E descobri que falta informação sobre o WinRT. Espero que não falte sobre o Xamarin. Mas isso é assunto para mais tarde :)

Comment: No Xamarin você vai usar as APIs nativas, então a informação que vai precisar é como criar Views no Android e no iOS e depois só portar a linguagem. As  bibliotecas são as mesmas e mapeadas 1-1. Você já pensou em coisas mais multiplataforma tipo o GTK ou outras parecidas?

Comment: Prefiro as APIs nativas. Na prática o GTK só é bom no Linux. E a maioria dos bindings dele estão defasados. Mas não estou tão preocupado agora porque é um produto que está parado por enquanto.