# Documentação sobre WPF com código C# puro

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, documentação

WPF é o que há de "novo" para desenvolvimento, não só desktop como também mobile. Porém, quase todo o material que se encontra disponível sobre WPF está totalmente atrelado ao uso da IDE e XAML.

Mas XAML é uma linguagem intermediária, ela é compilada para código C#, que depois é compilado para o executável final. Sendo assim, é possível excluir o XAML e codificar diretamente em C#.

Entendo que isso é impraticável do ponto de vista da produtividade, mas acredito que é importante também conhecer a API.

Pergunta:

Onde posso encontrar a documentação sobre a biblioteca de classes do WPF? Sei que provavelmente está no domínio MSDN, mas honestamente eu tenho uma dificuldade tremenda em encontrar alguma coisa lá. Acho o site pouco amigável.

[off] Taí uma coisa que a MS deveria aprender com as comunidades *open source*, elaborar documentação.

Comment: Realmente o site é pouco amigável. Olha, eu estava programando ultimamente usando WinForms e migrei pra WPF, eu nem sei oque é esse XAML, estou usando normalmente como se fosse um WinForms e até agora não encontrei barreiras

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/900/101.

Comment: Não acho que o WPF é o que "há de novo" no cenário de desenvolvimento pra Windows. Parece que ele deixou de ser o foco principal em favorecimento do Universal Windows Platform (UWP). Este deve receber mais inovações, mas o WPF não vai morrer tão cedo.

Comment: @rodorgas você está correto, eu estava misturando as coisas pelo fato de ambos usarem XAML tanto `UWP` quanto `WPF`.
Achei que tudo era WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A documentação é o Docs da Microsoft, especificamente o [`namespace Windows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O ponto de partida da documentação é a [FCL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

WPF tem 10 anos (na data que escrevi isto) e é usado apenas para desktop. Hoje pode ser usado com o .NET Core ou .NET 5 (que é o Core) para frente.

Comment: WPF não é também usando no desenvolvimento de aplicações para `Windows Phone` e no novo conceito de `Universal Apps` ?

Comment: Uma outra dúvida o código XAML é convertido em tempo de compilação ou execução?

Comment: Não. Há uso de XAML, não de WPF, são coisas completamente distintas. Já é outra pergunta, mas isso é meio complicado. Há uma conversão para BAML em tempo de compilação e este é convertido para CIL em tempo de execução.