# Linguagem empregada a um title designer do aplicativo VMIX

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, xaml

Qual a linguagem utilizada para trabalhar com Title Designer? Esse title trabalha com um aplicativo que faço uso no meu cotidiano no trabalho.

Se possível algum livro que sirva de referencia para estudo do mesmo.

Código abaixo:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                     mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1920" Height="1080"
                     xmlns:my="clr-namespace:vMixTitleLibrary;assembly=vMixTitleLibrary">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="0:0:1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image1">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="236"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Programme">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="236"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image2">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-476"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard2" RepeatBehavior="0:0:0.5">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image1">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="236"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Programme">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="236"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Image2">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-476"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="UpNextAnimatedBar.png" Name="Image1" Width="1199" Height="100" Margin="48,871,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image Source="UpNextAnimatedText.png" Name="Image2" Width="368" Height="177" Margin="41,735,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <my:TextBlockDesign Fill="#FF000000" FontSize="64" Text="Programme Title" Name="Programme" Width="984" Height="74" Margin="223,885,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <my:TextBlockDesign.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </my:TextBlockDesign.RenderTransform>
        </my:TextBlockDesign>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Esta linguagem é o [XAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language). Mas só uma parte da aplicação é escrita nela. Você precisará descobrir todo o resto. Possivelmente C# é usada para a programação em si. XAML é uma [linguagem de marcação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227443/101), é declarativa.

Isto é usado para WPF, UWP e Xamarin, entre outras tecnologias. Tem variações dependendo do que está usando. Pelo que percebo este código é para WPF.

[Pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/900/101).

Comment: Então, neste formato que passei ele é usado para criar uma animação ou titulo, tipo nomes de apresentadores de um jornal. Eu nem sabia que existia uma linguagem chamada XAML, sabe onde posso conseguir alguns livros sobre a mesma?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Em livrarias tem bastante.